# Printing spaces in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, spaces

I was playing with SQL Server at Hackerrank and I tried to print some spaces and something else after it.

I tried using the code:

```
PRINT space(5) + replicate('a',3)
```

but I didn't get the five spaces, just the three a's.

I also tried using `REPLICATE(' ',5)`, but it also didn't work.

Can anybody please tell me if there is a problem with my SQL code or if it's just a hackerrank problem?

Answer (score 1):

No repro:

```
PRINT space(5) + replicate('a',3)
```

outputs the spaces before the a's:

```
     aaa

Completion time: 2020-03-28T18:06:55.8805131-05:00
```

Comment: Thanks! it probably may be a problem of the web page